# UK visit visa extension before entering the UK

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, visa-extensions

My parents have a UK visit visa, which expires on November 11, 2018. They have never entered the UK. Is it possible to extend the visa under such circumstances?

Comment: Have you checked if November 11 is the date they have to leave, or if it is the last day they can enter? Sometimes visas say that you can enter any day between A and B, and once you have entered you can stay for up to N days.

Comment: @TorKlingberg for UK Visas the last date of their validity is the one by which you have to *Leave*. You can enter on the last date but then you'll have to leave on the same date.

Answer (score 13):

There would seem to be no reason to *extend* a visa whose holder is not inside the UK. Just apply for a new visa in the regular way.

Answer (score 6):

The Immigration Rules App V8 indicates that extending a Visit Visa can only be done while in the UK and in specific circumstances https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules